# Ruby: undefined method `>'

Tags: ruby, comparison, loops, while-loop

I just started learning Ruby and I ran into a problem today.

```
numResults = /\d+/.match(ie.div(:id, 'results_label').text)
puts "Results found: "+numResults.to_s

while(numResults > 0)
.
. some more code
.
```

I get this error in my output:

> ```
> Exception: undefined method `>' for #<MatchData:0x424c6d4>
> ```

Which is really strange because I made a while loop in IRB and it worked fine.
I can't get the code inside the loop to execute because the program sticks at the condition.

Anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`numResults` is a `MatchData` object and can't be compared with the `>` method. You need to convert it to a string, then convert the string to a number:

```
while(numResults.to_s.to_i > 0)
```

Answer (score 6):

In cases where the string  doesn't match the expression, `numResults` will be `nil`

so if thats what you are testing for, you'll want

```
while( !numResults.nil? ){ 

}
```

In cases where the string *does* match the expression, `numResults` won't be `nil` , and additionally, will contain the number of matches ( only 1 at most here because you don't have a repeating match ) in `numResults.size`

Also, other posters need to keep in mind that `numResults` contains no number of matches found, but contains the value of the *actual* match from the text data.

While

```
numResults.to_s.to_i
```

Might work, its only due to the grace of `nil.to_s.to_i == 0`.

If you were relying on `numResults` to be anything meaningful in terms of regex match count, you were looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks Kent, your answer was also really helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your while condition to:

```
while(numResults.to_i > 0)
```

This will force the numResults to an integer. It looks like it is being returned as a string from you regexp matcher.

Comment: People voting this up are not aware of the fact that `MatchData.to_i` does not in fact exist.  `nil.to_i` exists, but not `MatchData.to_i`

Comment: Works in 1.9.3 and 2.0.0. So it's valid now.